# Use TumblingWindow on join operation but no element is transported to my JoinFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink

```
public class FlinkWindowTest {
    public static long timestamp = 1496301598L;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get the execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        // get input data by connecting to the socket
        SourceFunction<String> out = new OutSource();
        DataStream<String> text = env.addSource(out);
        // parse the data
        DataStream<WordWithCount> windowCounts = text
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
                    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                        for (String word : value.split(" ")) {
                            out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
                        }
                    }
                });
        //assign timestamp
        windowCounts = windowCounts.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyTimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(0)));
        windowCounts.keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
                .join(windowCounts)
                .where(new MyKeySelector()).equalTo(new MyKeySelector())
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .apply(new JoinFunction<WordWithCount, WordWithCount, Object>() {
                    public Object join(WordWithCount wordWithCount, WordWithCount wordWithCount2) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("start join");
                        System.out.println(wordWithCount.toString());
                        System.out.println(wordWithCount2.toString());
                        WordWithCount wordWithCount3 = new WordWithCount(wordWithCount.word, wordWithCount.count + wordWithCount2.count);
                        System.out.println(wordWithCount3.toString());
                        return wordWithCount3;
                    }
                });

        env.execute("Window WordCount");
    }
    public static class MyKeySelector implements KeySelector<WordWithCount, String> {
            public String getKey (WordWithCount wordWithCount) throws Exception {
                return wordWithCount.word;
            }
    }
    public static class MyTimestampExtractor extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<WordWithCount> {
        public MyTimestampExtractor(Time maxOutOfOrderness) {
            super(maxOutOfOrderness);
        }

        public long extractTimestamp(WordWithCount wordWithCount) {
            return wordWithCount.getTimeStamp();
        }
    }
    public static class OutSource implements SourceFunction<String> {

        private String[] str = {
                "aa ff","bb gg","cc hh","dd kk"
        };
        public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) throws Exception {
            int index =0;
            while (true) {
                if(index == str.length)
                    index = 0;
                sourceContext.collect(str[index]);
                index++;
            }
        }
        public void cancel() {
        }

    }
    // Data type for words with count and timestamp
    public static class WordWithCount {

        public String word;
        public long count;

        public WordWithCount() {}

        public long getTimeStamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public WordWithCount(String word, long count) {
            this.word = word;
            this.count = count;
            ++timestamp;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return word + " : " + count;
        }
    }
}
```

This class is a demo. I create a SourceFunction to emit strings, then cut them to words. Finally I use join operation to join the stream itself. I don't care the count result.
The question is that there is no output in my JoinFunction class. I think the output should be

```
start join
aa : 1
aa : 1
aa : 2
start join
........
```

but now there is no output, because elements are in the window and not emitted to the join function. 
I don't have ideas about this situation. If there is anyone have advice, please tell me here. I expect replies by all.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to the set the time characteristic to event time:

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Comment: I have solved this problem. The problem is that the window never emit events, because the timestamp did not reached the limitation of the window. 

1. Add the time characteristic(use event time)
2. Update the timestamp smoothly in every event
3. Make sure that the timestamp can reach the window's limitation